# amazon s3 upload using javascript sdk is not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

i am using javascript amazon sdk for uploading content in to amazon. I try the example.this is my code.

```
  <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // See the Configuring section to configure credentials in the SDK
  // AWS.config.credentials = ...;
  AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'keyid', secretAccessKey: 'secretkey'});

 // Configure your region
  AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
 </script>


    <input type="file" id="file-chooser" /> 
    <button id="upload-button">Upload to S3</button>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucket_name'}});

    var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
    var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var file = fileChooser.files[0];
    if (file) {
         results.innerHTML = '';
         var cal_key = file.name;
         var params = {Key: cal_key, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
         bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {

         results.innerHTML = err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.';
       });
   } else {
      results.innerHTML = 'Nothing to upload.';
   }
   }, false);
  </script>
```

but i got this error

But i got this error

```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://bucket_name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Chrysanthemum.jpg. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://testing.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

After some research i know that this is a cross domain issue. But i don't know how solve this. This code is directly taken from amazon documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is effectively a CORS problem. Have you check this part of S3 [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/EnableCorsUsingREST.html).

This [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html#Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing__CORS_) must be usefull too :)